# Java to C# using JNI results in StackOverflowException

Tags: java, c#, c++, dll, java-native-interface

***1. Summarize the problem:***

I would like to invoke a C# method by invoking a Java method to check license file. This license check is performed by using a C# dll. I'm using JNI and a C++ wrapper. I will provide necessary source code below.
The C# dll has a method `public static string GetLicenseStatus()` implemented which I wrote a wrapper for and now I'm trying to invoke this method from Java application.
I'm using jdk-17.0.2.8-hotspot from Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit) and IntelliJ IDEA as Java IDE and Visual Studio 2022 for C# project.

After Java method invocation I expect that it returns a String (number from 0-4, not valid, valid, expired, ...) but it results in a StackOverflowException when C# code is being executed/accessed.

***2. Describe what you've tried***

I also tried to return just a value in the C++ method without calling any C# code; this worked fine. So **JNI <--> C++ wrapper is working fine**.

Also I tried to run C# source code within a C# main class, that was also working fine. So **there's no faulty C# code.**

Good to know is maybe also that I tried to create an own C# dll to confirm that the issue is not related to the license dll (that's why I writing before about a "C# project in Visual Studio"). This dll is very basic and is just checking for dummy username & password. Even When I tried to just return true in the function, when invoking it from Java it resulted again in a StackOverflowException in Java IDE. Its running into this error when attempting to instantiate an object with `gcnew`. My own created C# class and also the C# license dll were added as reference in the C++ project.

Maybe also worth to mention:

- The C# dll is relying on another dll to process license checking I assume.
- I observed that Visual Studio for some reason doesn't recognise imported header files. I have to add them manually in visual Studio and copy paste code into the manual created file.

***3. Show some code***

"Authenticator.java":

```java
package org.example;

public class Authenticator {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CppAuthenticator");
    }

    public native boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
    public native String getLicenseStatus();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program start");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
        System.out.println("Authenticator created");
        /**boolean valid = authenticator.authenticate(args[0], args[1]);
        System.out.println("Is valid?: "+valid);
        if(!valid) {
            System.err.println("Not valid!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }**/
        System.out.println("License Check...");
        System.out.println("Status: "+authenticator.getLicenseStatus());
    }
}
```

"CppAuthenticator.cpp"

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include "CppAuthenticator.h"
#include "org_example_Authenticator.h"
// this is the main DLL file.
#include <string>

using System::Text::Encoding;

String^ toString(const char* chars) {
    int len = (int)strlen(chars);
    array<unsigned char>^ a = gcnew array<unsigned char> (len);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        a[i] = chars[i];
    }
    return Encoding::UTF8->GetString(a);
}

bool authenticate(const char* username, const char* password) {
    SharpAuthenticator::Authenticator^ a = gcnew SharpAuthenticator::Authenticator();   // Fails here
    return a->Authenticate(toString(username), toString(password));
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_example_Authenticator_authenticate
(JNIEnv* env, jobject c, jstring username, jstring password) {
    jboolean isCopyUsername;
    const char *c_username = env->GetStringUTFChars(username, &isCopyUsername);
    jboolean isCopyPassword;
    const char* c_password = env->GetStringUTFChars(password, &isCopyPassword);
    jboolean result = authenticate(c_username, c_password);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(username, c_username);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(password, c_password);
    return result;
}


String^ getLicenseStatus() {
    return LicenseCheck::ValidateLicense::GetLicenseStatus();                       // Fails here
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_example_Authenticator_getLicenseStatus
(JNIEnv* env, jobject c) {
    String^ cliString = getLicenseStatus();
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    const char* utf8String = context.marshal_as<const char*>(cliString);
    jstring result = env->NewStringUTF(utf8String);
    return result;
}
```

"SharpAuthenticator.cs":

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SharpAuthenticator
{
    public class Authenticator
    {
        public bool Authenticate(String username, String password)
        {
            return username == "user" && password == "pass";
        }
        public bool Authenticate1()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the project structure I have in Visual Studio ("org_example_Authenticator.h" code was created with "javac -h ..."-command located in bin folder of JDK mentioned above.)
[image: Project structure in Visual Studio 2022]

Here are the C++ project properties in Visual Studio:
[image: General]
[image: VC++ Directories]

Here are C# project properties for my own created dummy dll mentioned above:
[image: C# project properties]

Comment: Is C++<-->C# working fine too? Where does StackOverflowException throw? How does the stack look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite familar with setting up Visual Studio projects. At the moment the C++ project is not defined as a console application. As a next step I will create a new project with a C++ console application in VS and adding the existing SharpAuthenticator project to be able to reply to your question. I let you know as soon as I manage to do it. But C++ <--> C# is something worth to check, I agree!

Comment: Ok... C++ <--> C# works. I printed the return value (bool) onto the console in my C++ application and it showed "0" or "1".

Comment: Does anyone sees an obvious mistake in the code or in the property parameters in one of the screenshots? I would appreachiate every little help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake... It cost me 1.5 days figuring out that I forgot to increment `i` in the while loop in `toString` method of "CppAuthenticator.cpp".
Here the correct working method:

```
String^ toString(const char* chars) {
    int len = (int)strlen(chars);
    array<unsigned char>^ a = gcnew array<unsigned char> (len);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        a[i] = chars[i];
        i++;
    }
    return Encoding::UTF8->GetString(a);
}
```